# How to reset everything Heroku in my Git/Rails 3.1 Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, reset

I solved my problem while writing this post, but I thought this might be good information for other noobs like me :)

To solve the problem below edit the following file
    .git/config

There's a section that looks like this

```
[remote "heroku"]
url = git@heroku.com:adjective-noun-1234.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

This is what git tries to push to. Just change the line

```
url = git@heroku.com:adjective-noun-1234.git
```

to whatever new Heroku project you created. Git should now be able to push to Heroku again.

---

---

I have gotten my second Rails app ever to a working state and want to deploy it. So I followed all the steps for Heroku deployment in the Ruby on Rails Tutorial (I had the deployment working for the sample app from the book) using:

```
heroku create
```

I then push my project with

```
git push heroku master
```

The project doesn't work although I can't find any errors in the Heroku logs, all I get is:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it
>   shortly.

So I looked around the Heroku Support Section and found the official Rails 3.0 / 3.1 deployment guide:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

I went to the **Heroku Web Frontend > General Info > Destroy App** because I wanted to continue my efforts with a clean slate.

Following the guide I created a Heroku project for the cedar stack:

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

And push it to Heroku using

```
git push heroku master
```

**THE PROBLEM: for some reason git is still trying to push to the old Heroku project!!!**

resulting in an error

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 15):

Check your remote repositories, and update it to the new heroku name:

```
git remote -v
```

Then remove the heroku one that is wrong:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Then add the new one

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:sitename.git
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit extreme, but worked for me....

```
heroku destroy appname

heroku create 

git push heroku master
```